# Rails RESTful API connection with android

Tags: android, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-geocoder

Hi i have been learning rails for a bit , now i need to make some mobile applications android & IOS connecting to my webapp, I know that the API is used to make the connections like the endpoints / url and then the methods for each and everyone of them is used to make it, my problem how can i know or test that my API for the mobile is working properly?

I am currently doing the android par and i don't know where to start with that. can guys also help with pointing out where to learn them, i mean creating user's in my webapp , I used device so i need to make an android application to make user's , insert data into my PG(postgresql) , get some geolocaion (geocoder), from the webapp , but i don't know where to start with the android how to send and get data from that, also how to test if the API that i made is working properly....

any help willbe greatly appreciated specially links to tutorials for rails version 4.+

Answer (score 1):

I'm showing you the simplest way to do this things.

1. First make a json formatted api using rails. And you can make a URL that can accept GET method value(www.exmp.com?val=asd).
2. In your android application make a Class name **JsonParser**.

copy and paste the following code.

```
private String jsonurl;

public JsonParser(String url) {
    this.jsonurl = url;
}

public String fetchJSON(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(jsonurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(25000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        String data = convertStreamToString(stream);
        return data;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Check", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
private String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

3. After that make a Object of that class in a Asynctask thread. and also give the URL as a parameter.you will get the Json formatted data.

To get the actual data you need to make a **JSONObject** type object and call like this .

```
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(jsonData); // returning json formatted data
this.status = reader.getString("status");
```

Now you can make java Bean to get or set the value for further uses.

Comment: thank you for the info that really helped!, but now my problem lies with the user creation and entry as the webapp that i made in RoR 4.2use's device and i don't know how to do the proper authentication from android, and even the user creation T_T